# Firebase - What is the API Key

Tags: firebase, api-key

In Firebase, when we sign up , it gives us an API key for each firebase Url. But where is it used in a consuming application? The fireBase API does not provide any means to supply API Key.

**Security** : What prevents anyone to go ahead and write any object to the given firebase Url? How is the authorization managed?

Comment: For people looking for the 3.x and above API Key to insert in your initializeApp() config, see docs here:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Comment: Good response at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/1195652 on why the key isn't a security risk

Answer (score 24):

You can generate your api key at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=[YOUR-PROJECT]

Replace [YOUR-PROJECT] with your proyect ID.

Find more information at https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862

regards.

Comment: what does this gotta do with firebase?

Comment: Everything. Firebase is a Google product.

Answer (score 9):

*updated the links to the new Firebase website*

Your question is very timely, as Firebase just announced its full security suite a few days ago.

There's a nice intro screencast and docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

The "API Key" is the old name for a Firebase Secret. This is used to generate Authentication Tokens to prove to Firebase who users are. You can see docs on authentication here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: I did as the document says, but trapped by the error `FirebaseAuthClient is not defined` as I'm trying to use new `FirebaseAuthClient()`. So, what's wrong?

Comment: OK, I know... I **need to add the Firebase Simple Login JavaScript include**, but it doesn't tell us where the code exists. However, I found it at https://github.com/firebase/firetube...

Comment: ^ Is the correct answer.  You need to include <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-client.js"></script>

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps:

1. Login to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. Select your project
3. On the top left corner, you'll find Settings icon, click on **Project Settings**

[image: settings]

4. For **Web API key**, you can find in General Tab
   [image: web-api-key]
5. For **Server Key**, you can find under Cloud Messaging Tab
   [image: server-key]